# R - accessing elements of a named list

Tags: r, list, function

I am trying to access elements in a named list.

```
Personalized_Reader <- function(lambda){read.table(lambda, header = FALSE ,sep = '\t')}
ff <- list.files(path="PATH_TO_DIRECTORY", full.names=TRUE, pattern=".txt$")
myfilelist <- lapply(ff, Personalized_Reader) 
names(myfilelist) <- list.files(path="PATH_TO_DIRECTORY", full.names=FALSE, pattern=".txt$")
```

Now, I can access single columns within a file, e.g., `myfilelist$"FILE_1.txt"$V5` - but I can't figure out how to access my files using `names(myfilelist)`. For example, `names(myfilelist)[1]` yields `"FILE_1.txt"` but while `myfilelist$"FILE_1.txt"$V5` works fine, I am getting an `"Error: attempt to apply non-function"` when trying `myfilelist$names(myfilelist)[1]$V5`.

For context, I would like to pass the expression on to another function:

```
My_Function <- function(lambda){subset(myfilelist$lambda, myfilelist$lambda$V5 < 100)}
mynewlist <- lapply(names(myfilelist), My_Function)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that the `$`-operator really needs to get a name, not an expression that yields a name like `names(...)`.
You can use your desired acess via `names(myfilelist)[1]` if you use doublebrackets instead of the `$`, like

```
myfilelist[[names(myfilelist)[1]]]$V5
```

This selects the element of `myfilelist` with name `names(myfilelist)[1]`.